# SAS code for calculating cumulative return not working

Tags: sas

I am trying to calculate cumulative return of stocks using SAS. (Cumulative return is basically the sum of all returns of the same stock until this moment).

However, the following code is not working properly. It keeps returning void in the CUM_RETURN field.

return_sec is the stock return. CUM_RETURN is the cumulative return that i am trying to get. MIDPRICE is the stock price.

Everything but the cumulative return is working fine.

The data set RETURNOUTSET is sorted by symbol and time.

```
  data RETURNOUTSET;
    set NBBOOUTSET; by Symbol;
    /* retain the price from last second */
    retain MIDPRICE CUM_RETURN; 
    LAG_MIDPRICE = lag(MIDPRICE);
    LAG_CUMRETURN = lag(CUM_RETURN);
    /* Make sure we are calculating the same ticker*/
    return_sec = (MIDPRICE - LAG_MIDPRICE) / LAG_MIDPRICE;
    if first.symbol then CUM_RETURN = 0;
    else CUM_RETURN  = return_sec + LAG_CUMRETURN;
    RMIN = 0.01/MIDPRICE;
    drop LAG_MIDPRICE LAG_CUMRETURN BB BO MIDPRICE;
  run;
```

I am thinking - where went wrong?

Comment: As indicated you're making a whole bunch of mistakes. You should never have to use if symbol=lag(symbol) in SAS, that's what BY group processing is for, read the chapter in the docs regarding BY group processing and then post an updated question including sample data with expected output. You can likely get it working this way, but it would be really bad code...at the end of the day that's your decision I suppose.

Comment: @Reeza I updated the code. I am suspecting the problem lies with the way I am using lag(CUM_RETURN). If I delete the lag(CUM_RETURN) statement, let CUM_RETURN  = return_sec; , there is value in CUM_RETURN. If I add the lag(CUM_RETURN)  back, it all became empty ...

Comment: I see you've marked this answered, is your problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 else 
      return_sec = .;
      CUM_RETURN = .;
```

What do you think that's doing?

It's setting `return_Sec=.` if `symbol ne lag(symbol)`, which is probably what you want.

It's also setting `CUM_RETURN = .` for every row.  That's probably undesired.  You want a `do...end` around that group, I suspect, adjacent to `else`.

```
else do;
  retun_sec = .;
  cum_return = .;
end;
```

or

```
else call missing(of retun_sec cum_return);
```

Comment: Yea it makes sense. However, I changed it to the do; end; loop but it seems that the CUM_RETURN is still 0 ...

Comment: there is value in return_sec though. I made sure that.

Comment: You don't have a `by` statement either so first.symbol doesn't work.

Comment: But honestly I don't think that is right either. You need to spend time working this out, there isn't enough info here to fully solve I don't think.

Comment: Do I need to add the by statement right after set NBBOOUTSET;? For example, set NBBOOUTSET by symbol? I didn't use a by because  NBBOOUTSET was already sorted in the previous steps ....

Comment: I don't know because I can't tell what you're trying to do. `by symbol` is unlikely to be right if you're lagging symbol though.

Comment: I just want to make sure that the returns of the stock are calculated using the prices of the same symbol (i.e. stock). For example, it doesn't make sense to subtract the price of Facebook from the price of Apple. It only makes sense when you subtract the price of Apple from the price of Apple. The NBBOOUTSET is already pre-sorted by Symbol Date Time.

Comment: I tried set NBBOOUTSET; by Symbol Date Time;. But it seems that it is still not working ...

Comment: I think the problem lies with the lag(CUM_RETURN) thing. When I wrote CUM_RETURN  = return_sec + LAG_CUMRETURN;, CUM_RETURN values are 0. But when I delete the LAG_CUMRETURN, CUM_RETURN is no longer 0 ...

Comment: could you provide a small sample of your input data and a small sample of you output data to go with it?